# How to Fix the Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability in jquery.ui.dialog.js in the Dialog widget in jQuery UI

Tags: security, jquery-ui, opencart, xss, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using opencart 1.5.6 and I am facing an issue,

Issue : "Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability in jquery.ui.dialog.js in the Dialog widget in jQuery UI" .

The jquery ui version 1.8.16 is been used in the application. Need help in fixing this issue. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the [Title XSS vulnerability](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6016)? You cannot really *fix* it in your code, but you can make sure to not pass anything that originates from user input as dialog titles (or html encode it beforehand). While this does not fix jQuery UI, it mitigates the risk in your application. (But you have to remember to do it everywhere, and in future changes too, which is not very good.)

Most of the times you should not be fixing 3rd party library vulnerabilities. Generally, the library gets fixed anyway, you just have to update, and that seems to be the case here. Use the latest verson of jQuery UI and it should be fine.

**Edit:**

In your case with OpenCart, this may mean upgrading OpenCart itself to its latest version, because as far as I can see, 1.5.6 depends on the vulnerable jQuery version. Whether your application is actually vulnerable to XSS or not depends on how OpenCart uses jQuery UI and whether it passes user input as dialog titles.

I assume you got this as a penetration test report finding, and the tester may have seen the vulnerable version of jQuery - that does not necessarily mean the vulnerability in your application is actually exploitable. Of course it may be.

Upgrading 3rd parties to recent versions regularly is a good practice, which helps with these kind of vulnerabilities.